# Will lex/flex correctly parse all tokens in `FILE yyin` after create buffer with `yy_create_buffer(yyin, YY_BUF_SIZE )`?

Tags: file, buffer, flex-lexer, lex

in lex/flex, there's a function `yy_create_buffer`, for example:

```
bp = yy_create_buffer(yyin,YY_BUF_SIZE );
```

it create buffer `bp` for `FILE yyin`, which size is `YY_BUF_SIZE`.

I wonder if `FILE yyin` is too large that `YY_BUF_SIZE` cannot contain all the text, will lex/flex parse all the token correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A flex buffer stores a part of the input, along with enough information to continue processing input. You don't have to worry about how much input there is.

The original lex scanner did not buffer. It just read input one character at a time, building up the current token in the character array `yytext`. This worked fine when tokens were not too big, but it is not the most efficient solution. So flex attempts to speed up the scan by reading a buffer of data at a time. Flex also avoids having to copy every token by just using the data directly from the buffer; in flex, `yytext` is a pointer into the buffer rather than being a separate array.

In addition to speeding up input handling, flex buffers give you a number of extra features, including the ability to provide in-memory buffers and a buffer stack useful for handling things like `#include` directives.

The only memory limitation is the size of a token. Each token must fit in memory while it is being processed. When the scan of a pattern hits the end of the buffer, flex will first shift the token to the beginning of the buffer and then if necessary attempt to resize the buffer.

The size you provide in the call to `yy_create_buffer` is the initial buffer size, not its limit. Faced with an enormous token, flex will continue to expand the buffer if necessary until memory allocation fails. Obviously, it is theoretically possible to have a token so large that this is not possible. So don't use a pattern like `(.|\n)+` if you are expecting your input streams to contain petabytes of data. :-)

In the original lex `yytext` was an array, not a pointer, resizing was impossible and the compile-time array size set a fixed limit on token length. Flex is an improvement in this regard, but it is not optimised for large tokens and there are some performance issues when your application tries to handle megabytes of data as a single token.